# Restricting android app to phone only issue

Tags: android, android-manifest

Going through other posts here and the android documentation, I added `<compatible-screens>` to my android manifest file to restrict my app only to phones. However whenever I try running it on the Nexus 7 tablet, the app shows up on tablet. Below is my android manifest file. Am I missing anything?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.testapplication" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However whenever I try running it on the Nexus 7 tablet, the app shows up on tablet

Sure. If you are manually running the app on the device, it will run.

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html):

> The Android system *does not* read the `<compatible-screens>` manifest element (neither at install-time nor at runtime). This element is informational only and may be used by external services (such as Google Play) to better understand the application's compatibility with specific screen configurations and enable filtering for users.

Comment: Ah ok... Thanks CommonsWare! I think I just read that google play service reads it for the play store but missed reading that the android system doesn't read it.